# How can we access a model's property from a JQuery within view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

My model has one field that contains collection of items. I want to access that collection from a jquery from the view that is bound with this particular model.

how can I achieve this?

Comment: from a jquery? what do you mean exactly

Comment: I have written javascript functions in my MVC view under scripts section.. I want to access some properties of the model from this javascript or using $ function.

Comment: Model?? you mean a server side ViewModel? i.e C# or VB Class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a slick way to do it.  Build up a JSON data object via a foreach loop.  Loading you data via an ajax call would be better, but that is a diferent solution for a different day.

Here I assume you have a collection of items that at least has an Id, and Name property.  You will want to make your @foreach loop a little better than mine because JSON does not really allow the extra ',' at the end of the last item.

```
var data = [
    @foreach (var item in Model.MyCollection)
    {
        <text>{"key":"@item.Id", "value":"@item.Name"},</text>
    }
];
$.each(data, function(i) {
    alert(data[i].key + ": " + data[i].value);
});
```

Comment: Oh, using Razor view engine in this example.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable reply. I think I am near to the solution. But I am getting $.data is undefined error, while my markup is as follow:

Comment: <div style="visibility:visible;">
var data = [
        {"id":"1", "ui_bgcolor":"Green", "ui_forecolor": "Black"},
        {"id":"2", "ui_bgcolor":"Amber", "ui_forecolor": "Black"},
        {"id":"3", "ui_bgcolor":"Red", "ui_forecolor": "White"}
]
</div>
 
 
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SetGradeDLLItemStyling() {
        $.each(data, function (i) {
            alert(data[i].UIBackgroundColor);
        });
    }
</script>

Comment: Needs to be in Script block.  On my cell, might not be seeing your comment correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I do something like this, not sure how 'correct' it is, but it works and makes sense to me.

```
var view = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('window'),
    render: function() {
        var that = this;
        var model = new myModel();
        model.fetch({
            success: function({
                that.dataModel = model;
            });
        });
    }

});
```

And then anywhere you can do this.dataModel and it should be your model